# Adding & moving columns doesn't completely remove the column from its original position in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel, tablecolumn

I am creating a set of tables in different tabs of a `JTabbedPane`. The tables get rendered.

I also add a column using `DefaultTableModel` and move the column to the 0th index for all tables using `JTable`.

Now column gets moved but it is not removing the header and empty rows of the moved column. Only first table in all tabs the column added gets moved without any remains in previous position.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) A couple of points: 1. PLEASE DON'T SHOUT. *(I've removed the shouting for you.)* 2. Code is worth 1024 words.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: "When using a sorter, always remember to translate cell coordinates."—[_loc. cit._](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.